# "summarise_at" and "mutate_if" for descriptive statistics for character variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `summarise_at` and `mutate_at` on multiple character variables at the same time. I have looked at many examples that use integer variables, but I just can't figure it out for character variables. Directly below is the code I use to produce descriptive statistics for a character (or factor) variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

# First block of code
starwars %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>%
  mutate(totalN = (cumsum(n))) %>%
  mutate(percent = round((n / sum(n)), 3)) %>%
  mutate(cumpercent = round(cumsum(freq = n / sum(n)),3))
```

This produces:

```
A tibble: 5 x 5
         gender     n totalN percent cumpercent
          <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1        female    19     19   0.218      0.218
2 hermaphrodite     1     20   0.011      0.230
3          male    62     82   0.713      0.943
4          none     2     84   0.023      0.966
5          <NA>     3     87   0.034      1.000
```

I would like to produce this same thing, but for multiple character (or factor) variables at once. In this case, let's use the variables `gender` and `eye_color` This is what I have tried:

```
starwars %>%        
      summarise_at(vars(gender, eyecolor) (n = n()) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(gender, eyecolor) (totalN = (cumsum(n))) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(gender", "eyecolor) (percent = round((n / sum(n)), 3)) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(gender, eyecolor) (cumpercent = round(cumsum(freq = n / sum(n)),3))))))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function
```

I understand that there are built-in functions called using `funs`, but I don't want to use them. I have tried playing with the code in many different ways to get it to work, but have come up short.

What I would like to produce, is something like this:

```
A tibble: 5 x 5
         gender     n totalN percent cumpercent
          <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1        female    19     19   0.218      0.218
2 hermaphrodite     1     20   0.011      0.230
3          male    62     82   0.713      0.943
4          none     2     84   0.023      0.966
5          <NA>     3     87   0.034      1.000

A tibble: 15 x 5
      eye_color     n totalN percent cumpercent
          <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1         black    10     10   0.115      0.115
2          blue    19     29   0.218      0.333
3     blue-gray     1     30   0.011      0.345
4         brown    21     51   0.241      0.586
5          dark     1     52   0.011      0.598
6          gold     1     53   0.011      0.609
7 green, yellow     1     54   0.011      0.621
8         hazel     3     57   0.034      0.655
9        orange     8     65   0.092      0.747
10         pink     1     66   0.011      0.759
11          red     5     71   0.057      0.816
12     red, blue    1     72   0.011      0.828
13       unknown    3     75   0.034      0.862
14         white    1     76   0.011      0.874
15        yellow    11     87   0.126     1.000
```

Perhaps a loop would be better? Right now I have many lines of code to generate the descriptive statistics for each character variable because I have to run the first block of code (noted above) for each variable. It would be great if I could just list the variables I would like to use and run each through the first block of code.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your desired output should look like? I suspect your problem is that you need to `group_by(gender, eye_color)`, then use the `mutate()` calls in your first example, rather than using `mutate_at()`, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed with crazybilly. Using `mutate_at` on factor variables implies you want do calculations on those variables - but things like `cumsum` and division aren't defined for factors. Maybe you want to create multiple columns at once? Or maybe you just need the grouping? Can't tell without sample output. (Notice that in your first example, you only use `gender` in the `group_by`, it's not used inside `mutate` at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your expected output, `mutate_at` is not what you want, since it mutates on the columns selected. What you wanted to do is to `group_by` `gender` and `eye_color` separately. This is a good place to write your summary code into a function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

summary_func = function(group_by_var){
  group_by_quo = enquo(group_by_var)
  starwars %>%
    group_by(!!group_by_quo) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(totalN = (cumsum(n)),
           percent = round((n / sum(n)), 3),
           cumpercent = round(cumsum(freq = n / sum(n)),3))
}
```

**Result:**

```
> summary_func(gender)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
         gender     n totalN percent cumpercent
          <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1        female    19     19   0.218      0.218
2 hermaphrodite     1     20   0.011      0.230
3          male    62     82   0.713      0.943
4          none     2     84   0.023      0.966
5          <NA>     3     87   0.034      1.000

> summary_func(eye_color)
# A tibble: 15 x 5
       eye_color     n totalN percent cumpercent
           <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         black    10     10   0.115      0.115
 2          blue    19     29   0.218      0.333
 3     blue-gray     1     30   0.011      0.345
 4         brown    21     51   0.241      0.586
 5          dark     1     52   0.011      0.598
 6          gold     1     53   0.011      0.609
 7 green, yellow     1     54   0.011      0.621
 8         hazel     3     57   0.034      0.655
 9        orange     8     65   0.092      0.747
10          pink     1     66   0.011      0.759
11           red     5     71   0.057      0.816
12     red, blue     1     72   0.011      0.828
13       unknown     3     75   0.034      0.862
14         white     1     76   0.011      0.874
15        yellow    11     87   0.126      1.000
```

The idea is to make your summary code into a function so that you can apply the same code over different `group_by` variables. `enquo` from `rlang` takes the code supplied to `group_by_var` and bundles it with the environment where it was called into a `quosure`. You can then use `!!` to unquote the `group_by_quo` in the `group_by` step. This enables non-standard evaluation (i.e. typing `summary_func(gender)` instead of `summary_func("gender")`.

If you don't want to call `summary_func` for every variable you want to `group_by`, you can wrap your `dplyr` code in `map` from `purrr`, and unquote each argument of `group_by_quo` supplied as `...` arguments. Notice the change from `enquo` to `quos` to convert each argument of `...` to a list of `quosure`s:

```
summary_func = function(...){
  group_by_quo = quos(...)

  map(group_by_quo, ~{
    starwars %>%
      group_by(!!.x) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(totalN = (cumsum(n)),
             percent = round((n / sum(n)), 3),
             cumpercent = round(cumsum(freq = n / sum(n)),3))
  })
}
```

You can now do this:

```
summary_func(gender, eye_color)
```

or with a vector of character variable names to `group_by`:

```
group_vars = c("gender", "eye_color")
summary_func(!!!syms(group_vars))
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
         gender     n totalN percent cumpercent
          <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1        female    19     19   0.218      0.218
2 hermaphrodite     1     20   0.011      0.230
3          male    62     82   0.713      0.943
4          none     2     84   0.023      0.966
5          <NA>     3     87   0.034      1.000

[[2]]
# A tibble: 15 x 5
       eye_color     n totalN percent cumpercent
           <chr> <int>  <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         black    10     10   0.115      0.115
 2          blue    19     29   0.218      0.333
 3     blue-gray     1     30   0.011      0.345
 4         brown    21     51   0.241      0.586
 5          dark     1     52   0.011      0.598
 6          gold     1     53   0.011      0.609
 7 green, yellow     1     54   0.011      0.621
 8         hazel     3     57   0.034      0.655
 9        orange     8     65   0.092      0.747
10          pink     1     66   0.011      0.759
11           red     5     71   0.057      0.816
12     red, blue     1     72   0.011      0.828
13       unknown     3     75   0.034      0.862
14         white     1     76   0.011      0.874
15        yellow    11     87   0.126      1.000
```

Comment: Thanks so much @useR! This works perfectly. It also has helped me better understand functions in R by using an example that is relevant to me. Much appreciated.